# Adding Role When Someone Starts Livestreaming

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So I found some code to help me give someone a specific role when they start streaming and to remove that role when they stop streaming.

```
client.on('presenceUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
    const guild = newMember.guild;
    const streamingRole = guild.roles.find(role => role.id === 'streaming role');

    if (newMember.user.bot || newMember.presence.clientStatus === 'mobile' || oldMember.presence.status !== newMember.presence.status) return;

    const oldGame = oldMember.presence.game ? oldMember.presence.game.streaming: false;
    const newGame = newMember.presence.game ? newMember.presence.game.streaming: false;

    if (!oldGame && newGame) {         // Started playing.
      newMember.addRole(streamingRole)
        .then(() => console.log(`${streamingRole.name} added to ${newMember.user.tag}.`))
        .catch(console.error);
    } 

    else if (oldGame && !newGame) {  // Stopped playing.
      newMember.removeRole(streamingRole)
        .then(() => console.log(`${streamingRole.name} removed from ${newMember.user.tag}.`))
        .catch(console.error);
    }
});
```

For the most part, this code works but for some reason, some people aren't getting their role changed. They have no roles in the server to begin with and the bot is at a higher place on the list than the other members.

I have also added the role manually and after some time the role was automatically removed even though the person was still streaming.

Comment: I don't get what this part of the 3rd line is for : `oldMember.presence.status !== newMember.presence.status`

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you're using Discord.js v11, you code looks like to be working, except for the line where you're trying to find the role.

Using this `const streamingRole = guild.roles.find(role => role.id === 'streaming role');` means that you are trying to find a role ID equal to it's name, which obviously is incorrect.

You might want to replace it with this :

```
const streamingRole = guild.roles.find(role => role.name === 'streaming role');
```

Comment: Actually that part I changed from the ID to that name to hide the ID. Also the 3rd line I’m not sure either. I found someone else asking for adding a role to someone playing a new game. I had to find out how to modify that to work with streaming.

Comment: @QuazArxx added another answer, I hope it will help you to resolve your issue

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove this part from the third line :

```
oldMember.presence.status !== newMember.presence.status
```

because the old status and the new one will never be the same.

If you want to make sure that the user is streaming, you might want to check this instead :

```
newMember.presence.status?.activities[0].type !== 'STREAMING'
```

Comment: So should I put the second code you said as the bottom if statements to add or remove the role from them or in place of the first code you said to remove?

Comment: You should replace the old code with the new one I sent

Comment: But wait wouldn't that return if they do start streaming and not add the role to them?

Comment: @QuazArxx Wooops, please forgive my typo, it should be working now ^^'

Comment: So after changing the code, the bot is actually not working now so that code before was helping it work

Comment: @QuazArxx What do you mean by "The bot is not working" ? What's happening ?

Comment: Meaning it's literally doing nothing. Nobody is getting a role and the ones that already have the role aren't having it removed